# Get data from Stream class without using StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, snapshot

I want to get data from a Stream function without using StreamBuilder. How do I achieve this? Below is the function where I want to fetch data from.

```dart
Stream<List<Person>> watchAllPersons(limit, offset) => select(persons).watch();
```

Below is the function where I want to fetch data from `watchAllPersons()` without using StreamBuilder.

```dart
var xtraPersonsData;

int limit = 12;
int offset = 5;

Future loadMoreItems() {
    final personDao = Provider.of<PersonDao>(context);

    var getXtraPersons = personDao.watchAllPersons(limit, offset);

    StreamBuilder(
      stream: getXtraPersons, // a Stream<int> or null
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        var xtraPersons = snapshot.data ?? List();
        setState(() {
          xtraPersonsData = xtraPersons;
        });
        debugPrint('persons: ' + persons.toString());
        // return;
      },
    );
  }
```

I'm updating the `xtraPersonsData` variable with the new data inside the StreamBuilder above. This is not working because `xtraPersonsData` is returning `null`.

**Note** inside the `loadMoreItems()` I would like to fetch data from `getXtraPersons` without using a StreamBuilder.

Comment: `personDao.watchAllPersons(limit, offset).listen(print)` - read official `Stream.listen()` method documentation for more info

Comment: @pskink ok looking it up now.

Comment: and https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams - this is even better for the beginners

Comment: @pskink It worked thank you man. I checked this link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html

Comment: good job, also read the second link i posted !!

Comment: @pskink Yah just finished checking it out. They have explained in more detail there, I like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink the problem has been solved and the code is being minimized as well using code below for the solution.

```dart
personDao.watchAllPersons(limit, offset).listen(onData);

void onData(List<PersonWithProduct> event) {
    print(event);
  }
```

Docs [here](http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) and some tutorials [here](http://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams).