# How to get data from Stream without using StreamBuilder (and other Widgets) and .listen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `PaginatedDataTable` and passing data read from Cloud Firestore to `MyData` class. However, I don't know how to get past it. I referenced this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/uQC80o4jIzg) and found that it generates data in `MyData` class, **not** outside of `MyData` class, but I am getting data outside of `MyData` class. So I thought, how can I get data from `Stream` without using `StreamBuilder` (and other `Widget`s) and `.listen` and get the data in `MyData` class. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60613454/16124033) but the solution is to use `.listen`, I can't use `.listen` in `MyData` class.

My code:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Model>>(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data == null
        ? Container()
        : PaginatedDataTable(
            source: MyData(list: snapshot.data!),
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  "Name",
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  "Email",
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            columnSpacing: 20,
            horizontalMargin: 10,
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            showCheckboxColumn: false,
          );
  },
),
```

---

```
class MyData extends DataTableSource {
  MyData({required this.list}) : super();
  final List<Model> list;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
  @override
  int get rowCount => list.length;
  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: [
        DataCell(
          Text(
            list[index].name,
          ),
        ),
        DataCell(
          Text(
            list[index].email,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How to get data from `Stream` without using `StreamBuilder` (and other `Widget`s) and `.listen`? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: riverpod's `StreamProvider` also can do that for you. and if you are using firestore,  [firestoreQueryBuilder](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/firestore/) does has built-in pagination that can make you life easier.

Comment: @john can you answer this question and share the code?

Comment: Have you tried `flutter_bloc` if you are welcoming to `flutter_bloc` I can share the code to get data from Stream and use BlocBuilder to listen to the changes without using `StreamBuilder` and without `.listen`